# Quantum Brownian Motion - Calculation of moments

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, density-operator, brownian-motion

The master equation of quantum brownian motion is derived as \begin{equation}\frac{d}{dt} \hat{\rho_s}(t) = -i[\hat{H_S} + \frac{1}{2}M\tilde{\Omega}^2 \hat{X}^2 , \hat{\rho_s}(t)] -i\gamma[\hat{X}, \{\hat{P},\hat{\rho_s}(t)\}] - D[\hat{X}, [\hat{X},\hat{\rho_s}(t)]] -f[\hat{X}, [\hat{P},\hat{\rho_s}(t)]]    \end{equation}
where [.,.] indicates commutator and {.,.} indicates an anti-commutator, $\gamma, D$ and $f$ are constants and $$\hat{H_S} = \frac{1}{2M}\hat{P}^2 +  \frac{1}{2}M\Omega^2\hat{X}^2 .$$ I wante to evaluate $\frac{d}{dt} \langle\hat{P}\rangle_{t}$. I know that \begin{equation}\frac{d}{dt} \langle\hat{P}\rangle_{t} = \frac{d}{dt} Tr_S \{\hat{\rho_s}(t) \hat{P} \}  = Tr_S \{\frac{d \hat{\rho_s}(t) }{dt}  \hat{P} \}  \end{equation} But I am unable to get the answer as $ -M (\tilde{\Omega}^2 +\Omega^2 )\langle\hat{X}\rangle_{t} -2\gamma\langle\hat{P}\rangle_{t} $. Can someone help me with this?